# SSL error - certificate not identifying correct server

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https

SO I have set up my SSL certificate on my ubuntu/nginx server.
When I created the certificate the wizard on Gandi (the CA for the certificate) asked me to identify a subdomain for the certificate. I just gave a dummy subdomain (sslforall.example.com) as I was under the impression the the certificate would work to the main domain (example.com).

Having installed the certifiicate when I visit https://example.com I get an error message from my browser:

> This is probably not the site you are looking for! You attempted to
>   reach **example.com**, but instead you actually reached a server
>   identifying itself as **sslforall.example.com**. This may be caused by a
>   misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An
>   attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake
>   (and potentially harmful) version of **example.com**.

Any ideas how to solve? Do I need to remake the certificate?

Comment: Is 'mydomain.com' a placeholder for your actual domain?  I can go to https://mydomain.com/ just fine without any errors.

Comment: yes, I am using it as a placeholder

Comment: Please don't do that. Only use [actual example domains](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606).

Comment: I think you misread the [instructions](http://wiki.gandi.net/en/ssl/csr) which state: subdomain.example.com indicates the subdomain that you want to protect. This is the most important part. If you have a single-address certificate to activate, you should put in the full subdomain (e.g. foo.example.com). The www subdomain is added automatically by the CA, for example, example.com will secure both example.com and www.example.com If you have a wildcard certificate, you should put in a * for the subdomain (e.g. *.example.com). Wildcard certificates also secure the raw domain (with no subdomain).

Comment: Yes, on reflection you are correct. The reason I chose an arbitrary subdomain was my previous experience with StartSSL where their single domain certificate secures both the parent domain and a subdomain that you must provide. I assumed this was convention.